# c# label font Size to fit in its panel container

Tags: fonts, size, label, panel, fill

I have a form which has been designed by tablelayoutpanel.

In one cell I have a panel docked to that cell, and in the panel is a label docked to parent panel.

Label auto-size feature is set to false.

The size of font for the label must be dynamic so that when the form is re-sized (and hence the panel is re-sized) the label.text still fits and fills the panel without being cut.

I tried TextRenderer.MeasureText / measure string to find a proper size for the font but couldn't solve the problem.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show us your code? I know this can be done...

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a code snippet based on [this link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharpgeneral/thread/78256dfc-2929-40f6-8cb0-5a2d11db0bb8) that can help you:

```
using System.Drawing;

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public int initialWidth;
    public int initialHeight;
    public float initialFontSize;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        AutoScaleMode = AutoScaleMode.None;

        // Sets the initial size of the variables
        initialWidth = Width;
        initialHeight = Height;
        initialFontSize = LabelFont.Font.Size;
        LabelFont.Resize += LabelFont_Resize;
    }

    private void LabelFont_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SuspendLayout();
        // Get the proportionality of the resize
        float proportionalNewWidth = (float)Width / initialWidth;
        float proportionalNewHeight = (float)Height / initialHeight;

        // Calculate the current font size
        LabelFont.Font = new Font(LabelFont.Font.FontFamily, initialFontSize * 
            (proportionalNewWidth > proportionalNewHeight ? proportionalNewHeight : proportionalNewWidth), 
            LabelFont.Font.Style);
        ResumeLayout();
    }

}
```

Using this method of Label resizing, you determine the ratio of the change and define a new font from it. I hope this solves your issue.